# Find the top ranked unique item for each grouping in a set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Given the following dataset which contains a series of products for a customer, along with a number of related products for each, I want to pick the top ranked unique Related Product ID for each of the Product IDs.

### Sample Data

This table shows what the data looks like for a single Customer.  There will be multiple Customers.

The items selected in yellow are an example of what the results would look like for this example Customer ID.

[image: SQL example dataset]

So, a single Product ID may have multiple Related Product IDs.  For a single customer with, say 6 Product IDs, I want to return the top ranked Related Product ID for each individual Product ID.

### Rules

The catch is, that I want to eliminate duplication as much as possible.  So if the same Related Product ID is the top ranked for more than one Product ID, the selection should move down to the next highest ranked Related Product ID.

The goal is to, where possible, provide a unique (within each Customer ID) Related Product ID for each Product ID.

Where it is not possible for a unique Related Product ID to be selected (because there are only duplicate Related Product IDs available), then the top ranked should be selected.

### Results

For Product 2, the Related Product ID 23194 is the highest ranked, but it is not unique, so is skipped in favour of 23287.  For Product 4, we could use either 23194 or 23300, but because neither is unique, we take the highest ranked item.

I've tried doing this using a recursive CTE, but this will iterate through the items and allocate the Related Product on the first Products before finding out if the Related Products are repeated later in the set.

How else can I approach this?

Comment: So highest is lowest, "Product" is "Product Ranking" and "Customer ID" is just for show? Might you be able to provide a _clear_ and _consistent_ description of the algorithm you are trying to implement, step by step, including any other restrictions, requirements and desires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT OVER()`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03380/2/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = (RelatedProductRanking  + COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID)) * 
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY RelatedProductID)
    FROM tbl    
),
CteRnk AS(
    SELECT *,
        RNK = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY RN)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT 
    CustomerID, ProductRanking, ProductID, RelatedProductRanking, RelatedProductID
FROM CteRnk
WHERE RNK = 1
ORDER BY ProductRanking, RelatedProductRanking
```

**RESULT**

```
| CustomerID | ProductRanking | ProductID | RelatedProductRanking | RelatedProductID |
|------------|----------------|-----------|-----------------------|------------------|
|      12436 |              1 |     14553 |                     1 |            14481 |
|      12436 |              2 |     33017 |                     2 |            23287 |
|      12436 |              3 |     14203 |                     1 |            14289 |
|      12436 |              4 |     23038 |                     1 |            23194 |
|      12436 |              5 |     15120 |                     1 |            14520 |
|      12436 |              6 |     23014 |                     1 |            23300 |
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  I had to add the CustomerID to the PARTITION BY statements, as I have to run this for multiple customers, but this wasn't clear in my example originally.  This does the job brilliantly though, thanks.